# trpc - Calling a route inside itself

Tags: typescript, trpc.io

Based on the documentation [here](https://trpc.io/docs/server-side-calls), you can call another route on the server side using the `const caller = route.createCaller({})` function. However, if the route is within itself, is it possible to do so using the `this` keyword? If not, how can one call a route sibling?

```js
import { z } from "zod";

import { router, publicProcedure } from "../trpc";

export const exampleRouter = router({
  hi: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
    return "Hi there!";
  }),
  world: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
    return "World";
  }),
  hello: publicProcedure.query(async function () {
    const caller = this.createCaller({});
    const result = await caller.example.hi();
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know the answer to the exact question you asked, based on the link you provided for Server Side Calls, `createCaller` *should not* be used to call a procedure from within another procedure.

The documentation mentions that this will create overhead as it may need to create context again for each procedure call even if only one API call was made from the client.

So instead of something like your example code:

```js
import { procedure, router } from '../trpc'

export const myRouter = router({
    hi: procudure.query(() => 'hi'),
    hello: procedure.query(() => {
        const caller = createCaller({})
        return caller.myRouter.hi()
    })
})
```

You *should* be doing something like this:

```js
import { procedure, router } from '../trpc'

const getHi = () => {
    return 'hi'
}

export const myRouter = router({
    hi: procudure.query(() => getHi()),
    hello: procedure.query(() => getHi())
})
```

In that example, the logic used to get the information you want (just 'hi' in this case but it could be a database call) is abstracted so that in each case you still call the same code, but without the additional procedure call.